# Update Twitter status with an image in twython, keep getting API errors?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twython

Edit: Updated code. Just keep getting API errors.

How do I post an image from a URL with a status update to twitter using twython and python 3x? I've read the docs, but it only outlines opening local files in directories, and I've looked at a few threads on SO. Here's what I have so far, I'm getting error codes I don't know how to solve.

What do I change to get this image to post? This gives me `twython.exceptions.TwythonAuthError: Twitter API returned a 401 (Unauthorized), Could not authenticate you.`
the minute it hits `twitter.upload`

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError
import os
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO

import urllib
import requests

CONSUMER_KEY = os.environ['CONSUMER_KEY']
CONSUMER_SECRET = os.environ['CONSUMER_SECRET']
ACCESS_TOKEN = os.environ['ACCESS_TOKEN']
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = os.environ['ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET']
twitter = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
twitter.verify_credentials()

url = "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1127/4605090363_4a96e64ff1.jpg"

response = requests.get(url)
photo = requests.get(response.url).content
response = twitter.upload_media(media=photo)
twitter.update_status(status='Checkout this cool image!', media_ids=[response['media_id']])
```

This solution: `twitter.post('/statuses/update_with_media', params = {'status': 'Testing New Status'}, files = {'media': StringIO(photo)})`

Gives me a `TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes`

I can not get this to work. I have no idea anymore why. Its a primary account. I'm not using "sign in with twitter", its not a web app. Just a worker bot.

I am baffled, I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. It will post text statuses fine, I can search, get user timelines, send DMS, etc. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are missing a step here: https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage/advanced_usage.html#posting-a-status-with-an-editing-image  - You did not upload the image. You should have been accessing the `media_id` of the response of `upload_media`

Comment: Thank you! Missed that. Now I'm getting a "media parameter is missing" error code. Updated post. I really wish twitter would just let me pass a url. :-/

Comment: Ok. Now I'm just getting a 401 authentication error once it hits upload. Program i authenticated for read and write. It will still post just text updates. Weird. No idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This turns out to be a type error with respect to what twython expects when uploading media. Pulling an image down remotely and calling content on it gives us a `bytes` but twython wants an `io` object.

That there's a 401 in the stack trace is a red herring, but we can give twython what it wants by adding `io` and reading the request content into a `BytesIO`.

```
from twython import Twython, TwythonError
from io import BytesIO
import os

import urllib
import requests

CONSUMER_KEY = os.environ['CONSUMER_KEY']
CONSUMER_SECRET = os.environ['CONSUMER_SECRET']
ACCESS_TOKEN = os.environ['ACCESS_TOKEN']
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = os.environ['ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET']
twitter = Twython(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
twitter.verify_credentials()

url = "https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1127/4605090363_4a96e64ff1.jpg"

response = requests.get(url)
photo = BytesIO(response.content)
response = twitter.upload_media(media=photo)
twitter.update_status(status='Checkout this cool image!', media_ids=[response['media_id']])
```